# No module named flask-wtf in PyCharm

Tags: python, windows, flask, pycharm

When I run this code, `from flask_wtf import FlaskForm` I get an error,

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_wtf'
```

I've installed the flask-wtf package through CMD,

```
pip install flask-wtf
```

and it gave me the confirmation that the package has been successfully installed

```
Requirement already satisfied: flask-wtf in c:\users\zzz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (0.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: WTForms in c:\users\zzz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from flask-wtf) (2.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in c:\users\zzz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from flask-wtf) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous in c:\users\zzz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from flask-wtf) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.0 in c:\users\zzz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-wtf) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.0 in c:\users\zzz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-wtf) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=7.1.2 in c:\users\zzz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-wtf) (8.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\zzz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from click>=7.1.2->Flask->flask-wtf) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in c:\users\zzz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from click>=7.1.2->Flask->flask-wtf) (4.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in c:\users\zzz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.0->Flask->flask-wtf) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.4 in c:\users\zzz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata->click>=7.1.2->Flask->flask-wtf) (3.10.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\users\zzz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata->click>=7.1.2->Flask->flask-wtf) (3.5.0)
```

Comment: In pycharm, are you working on a virtual env? then your pkg needs to be installed on that virtual env. for example if I am in venv(as virtual env) then I can find installed packages with pip freeze.  (venv) (base) user@users-iMac SOtry % ` pip freeze`.

Comment: The problem was you were trying to pip install without activating the proper venv. The pip output shows you were trying to install to a Python base installation that already has some version of the package or its dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed by installing the `flask-wtf` package directly from PyCharm.

`ctrl` + `alt`+ `S` and then `Python Interpreters` hit the `+` sign and then type `flask-wtf` and download the package.